# Autocomplete for textbox input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete, textbox

I'm building a service website where one part requires users to enter the street name in a city and I'm planning to add Autocomplete functionality to the input field.

The number of my records of street names is about 2000, so my question is, which way should I use?

For jQuery or AJAX + PHP my concern is, that if the amount of the street names is too large it might effect the loading speed performance of the website.

Comment: you must use jQuery Ajax + PHP + MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You may try **[Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)**

Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery allows you to easily create autocomplete/autosuggest boxes for text input fields. It is free to download. You may try a demo auto filling Country Names in the homepage itself.

Hope this helps...

Comment: One more， which one is better in this condition?  list of 2000 shall i use local or ajax ?

Comment: Of course AJAX. Listing data in your page may make your document large, slower to load. Consider upvoting / accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/). Easy to use and user-friendly (search, multiselect, etc)

Answer (score 0):

it’s usually done with jquery or another ajax ‘framework’ (e. g. mootools) and php/whatever server side language (e. g. asp, jsp, etc.) you decide to use to feed the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Long street names should not slow down the performance, only the size of the database itself. But 2000 entries should really be feasible.

I suggest ajax in jQuery clientside to call a php script on the server side. The ajax will give php a string of what the user entered (e.g., on every keypress), then php will look for a streetname like that in the database (using `LIKE` in the query) and return, e.g., a json object with all street names that were found.